# Retrieving JSP Value Based on Table Row

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a table in my jsp that displays a list of files

```
<table id="files">
    <c:forEach items="${files}" var="file">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${file}" /></td>
            <td><a class="processLink" href="#"> Process </a></td>
            <td><a class="deleteLink" href="#"> Delete </a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

When a user clicks the "Delete" link on either table row, I'd like to launch an action and send the value of that row's `${file}` value as an argument to the function `deleteFile()`. Rather than setting the `onclick` attribute on the anchor itself and invoking the function, how can I grab the value of `${file}` using a js framework like jquery? Preferably without traversing the DOM?

```
$('.deleteLink').click(function(){ deleteFile(file)});
```

or YUI

```
Y.all('.deleteLink').on(
    'click',
    function(file){
    //delete file
```

Comment: Did you consider maybe somehow involving a numeric row id or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table id="files">
<c:forEach items="${files}" var="file">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${file}" /></td>
        <td><a class="processLink" href="#" data-id="${file}"> Process </a></td>
        <td><a class="deleteLink" href="#" data-id="${file}"> Delete </a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

> $('.deleteLink').click(function(){ deleteFile()});
>
> function deleteFile(e) {   if(e) {   e.preventDefault();
>   e.preventProgation();  }
>
> var f =    $(this).attr('data-id');
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="files">
<c:forEach items="${files}" var="file">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${file}" /></td>
        <td><a class="processLink" href="#" data-id="${file}"> Process </a></td>
        <td><a class="deleteLink" href="#" data-id="${file}"> Delete </a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```